# Measuring difference between 2 numbers in the same column using awk

Tags: linux, shell, awk

I have a file that contains a lot of columns. One column contain a list of number:

```
   asd "/$ 0
   asd /"$ 1
   add %$" 4
   add "/% 18
   ads "/% 24
   add "/% 30
```

I would like to write a script using awk that allows to measure the difference between the number contained in a row and the row before the previous row (exemple: the difference between the third row and the first row) 
So the output will be :

```
4
17
20
12
```

How can I do that ? 
(if you have a good tutorial about awk, I will be grateful)

Comment: The question is incomplete, you have given no handle on how you arrived at the other values in the sample output.

Comment: @tink, it looks like it makes sense to me.

Comment: You may also want to refer to GNU awk manual.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one method that uses the modulus operator to create an array that stores only the last elements needed for the calculation:

```
$ awk 'NR>2{print $3-a[(NR-2)%3]}{a[NR%3]=$3}' file
4
17
20
12
```

As for a good tutorial check out [**Effective AWK Programming**](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/).

Answer (score 3):

Code for [awk](/questions/tagged/awk):

```
$ awk '{c=b;b=a;a=$3} c!="" {print $3-c}' file
4
17
20
12
```

---

And more general, based on sudo_O's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17555295/2468910):

```
$ awk -v distance=1 'NR>distance{print $3-a[(NR-distance)%(distance+1)]}{a[NR%(distance+1)]=$3}' file
1
3
14
6
6

$ awk -v distance=2 'NR>distance{print $3-a[(NR-distance)%(distance+1)]}{a[NR%(distance+1)]=$3}' file
4
17
20
12

$ awk -v distance=3 'NR>distance{print $3-a[(NR-distance)%(distance+1)]}{a[NR%(distance+1)]=$3}' file
18
23
26
```

Comment: Same problem as @Carl Norum answers, fine for 2 lines back but won't scale beyond that.

Comment: yes, two lines back: `measure the difference between the number contained in a row and the row before the previous row`, as desired.

Comment: @sudo_O that's really fine, so you can have an "array of distances" :) - thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a quick program I just whipped up (comments inline):

```
BEGIN {
    # read the first line and save the number in 'a'
    getline
    a = $3        
    # read the second line and save the number in 'b'
    getline
    b = $3
}

# process the remaining lines
{
    # print difference of this line's number and the number two rows back
    print $3 - a

    # shuffle the record keeping variables
    a = b
    b = $3
}
```

Example running it on your test input:

```
$ awk -f example inputfile 
4
17
20
12
```

Comment: Yeah, your answer is better. =)